# FailedGeocode error from foursquare venues search api

Tags: python, geocoding, foursquare

I am trying to use the [4sq venues api](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) to search for a restaurant in New York. Not sure why I keep getting a failed geocode error.

These are the query params I am using -

```
params = {'ll': '40.7,-74', 'limit': 10, 'query': 'ele',
              'intent': 'browse', 'near': 'New York, NY'}

FailedGeocode: Couldn't geocode param near: New%20York,%20NY
```

Comment: Are you still noticing this happen?

Answer (score 0):

to query for venues using the foursquare api you need to provide **either** a 'll' (lat-long) **or** a 'near' (a city with or without state code) param. you have both, so you'll need to choose if you'd rather do:

```
params = {'ll': '40.7,-74','limit': 10, 'query': 'ele',
          'intent': 'browse}
```

or

```
params = {'near': 'New York, NY', 'limit': 10, 'query': 'ele',
          'intent': 'browse'}
```